# Android image from photo gallery

Tags: android, image

```
System.out.println("weeeeeeeee");
try {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    System.out.println("111111");
    System.out.println(Common.getIm1());
    Common.getIm1().setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("dakfls" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Whats happening basically in that onactivityresult function, its giving me the following error. dakflsAttempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference. Crash is happening before printing 1111.
And I need full image not thumbnail

I am calling the start from my fragment like this

```
try
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 100);
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: Why is everything inside try-catch ?

Answer (score 1):

To properly receive data from an `ACTION_PICK` you have to `getData()` on the `Intent`. Like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 100:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             Uri imageUri = data.getData();
             Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
             Common.getIm1().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Note: You should put your code `100` in a `static final int` at the top of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

And you will get picture path on your onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the data in the returned Intent, it content style Uri, and query or open it with ContentResolver

```
Uri dataUri = data.getData();
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
InputStream stream = contentResolver.openInputStream(dataUri); //if you sure this content Uri is refer a file
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 photoBrowseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, DataHolder.INTENT_BROWSE_GALLERY);
        }
    });
```

and use the uri of image as u wish to as follows

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == DataHolder.INTENT_BROWSE_GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();

        }
    }

}
```